# counting rows and joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `post` and `post_vote`. The `post` table stores an id.

And the `post_vote` table stores the id of the post to which the vote belongs, the name of the user, and the type of the vote (upvote/downvote).

There are other columns in each table and other tables but those are irrelevant.

My problem:

How can I get a table that has the info from the `post` table, joined with the count of upvotes and downvotes from the `post_vote` table next to the post they belong to in a row?

Example:

post:

```
+---------------------+
| post_id | title |...|
| 1       | ...   |...|
| 2       | ...   |...|
+---------------------+
```

post_vote:

```
+---------------------------------+
| post_id | voter_name | vote_type|
| 1       | user1      | UPVOTE   |
| 2       | user2      | DOWNVOTE |
+---------------------------------+
```

desired result from a query:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| post_id | title | ... | upvotes | downvotes|
| 1       | ...   | ... | 1       | 0        | 
| 2       | ...   | ... | 0       | 1        |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join `post` to a query that uses conditional aggregation in `post_vote` to count the votes:

```
select p.*, v.upvotes, v.downvotes
from post p 
left join (
  select post_id,
    sum(vote_type = 'UPVOTE') upvotes,
    sum(vote_type = 'DOWNVOTE') downvotes
  from post_vote
  group by post_id 
) v on v.post_id = p.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out

```
SELECT post.post_id, post.title, post.(...), (SELECT COUNT(vote_type) AS 'upvotes' FROM post_vote WHERE vote_type = 'upvote'), (SELECT COUNT(vote_type) AS 'downvotes' FROM post_vote WHERE vote_type = 'downvote') FROM post INNER JOIN post_vote ON post.post_id = post_vote.post_id
```